# I am unable to relate the normal distribution dependency for regression . I need a mathematical intuition cum understanding for regression assumptions

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption

What is the mathematical significance for the assumptions of linear regression to hold true for arriving at a single/multiple regression formula? Can anyone use the assumed normally distributed dataset to prove normal distribution properties in the simple/multiple linear regression formula.

We arrived at slope and intercept value from the dataset. We summarize the model post applying linear regression function. What is the significance of a normally distributed data in the prediction.

For all normal distributions, 68.2% of the observations will appear within plus or minus one standard deviation of the mean; 95.4% of the observations will fall within +/- two standard deviations; and 99.7% within +/- three standard deviations. This fact is sometimes referred to as the "empirical rule," a heuristic that describes where most of the data in a normal distribution will appear.

What use is this in our prediction? Can one use the dataset to reverse check the 'e' value which is 2.71.

Comment: Please do not reiterate. Your previous question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630320/what-is-the-mathematical-significance-for-regression-formula-to-hold-valid-with was closed for some reason. Since you are new to this site, take some time to understand what's wrong with it and learn how to ask proper questions; see for more details https://stats.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: It was closed as they needed more tags, they were ok with the question!! So I have tagged the relevant topics for the question. Cheers!